# How to use add-ons with CKEditor4 for Angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular-cli

I'm integrating CKEditor into an application we're building. We've always used TinyMCE, but when adding lots (I mean up to 100) inline editors on a single page, the whole application either crashes or takes more than 10 seconds to load. Switching to CKEditor 4 gave a huge performance boost, but...

**For some reason, the basic 'font color' button is not available by default.**

In both CKEditor 4 and 5 the add-ons are not 'just' easy-to-use npm packages like almost every other library, it's horribly inconvenient (understatement). The documentation is also seriously lacking, and you have 15 open tabs in no time, without a solution.

I followed the "Integration with Angular" guide, which was actually clear, but no mention of adding custom plugins. [There is a solution here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751957/how-to-implement-ckeditor-in-angular-app/50218611#comment100481435_50218611), but that doesn't work anymore, because of changes in how the `angular.json` file is handled.

**TLDR: How to use custom/downloaded plugins with CKEditor4 and Angular7-cli?**

Comment: did you find any answer to your problem ?

Comment: @ESCoder Nope, I gave up and switched back to TinyMCE

Answer (score 0):

Extract the downloaded plugin .zip into the plugins folder of your CKEditor4-angular.

add extraPlugins : 'colorbutton' to your config

Comment: there is no plugin folder in my CKEditor4-angular ? how to do this now ?