# how to get data from CKEditor?

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor

I am trying to get the data from CKEditor? I am trying getData function but it doesnt seem to be working.

Below is the HTML

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" id="Editor" [data]="editorData"></ckeditor>
```

Below is the Typescript

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
public Editor = ClassicEditor;
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#Editor'), {
      toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote'],
      heading: {
        options: [
          { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
          { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
          { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
        ]
      },
    }).then(newEditor => {
        this.Editor= newEditor;

      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

if I try this.Editor.getData() I am getting an error saying getData is not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the complete path:

1)  install the ckEditor as below:

```
npm i ng2-ckeditor --save
```

2) Add the ckEditor script in the index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

3) Add CkEditor Module to import section in AppModule like the following:

```
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';

imports:
[
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  CKEditorModule
],
```

4) Define the following line in the top of the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var CKEDITOR: any;
```

5) Define a specific name for your ckEditor  (default name is editor1): ***here I set content***

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (event, data) {
    var editor = event.editor,
    element = editor.element;
    editor.name = "content"
 });
}
```

6) in your app.component.html (add a ckEditor component and one button to get data):

```
<ckeditor #myEditor [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent" [config]="{uiColor: '#a4a4a4'}" debounce="500"> </ckeditor> <input type="button" value="Get Data" (click)="getData()" />
```

Now, if you want to get data, use the following command:

```
getData() {
  console.log(CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData());
}
```

[StackBlitz Here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqzeue)

**[DEMO](https://angular-rqzeue.stackblitz.io/)** (check your browser's console)

**For CKEditor Classic**:

If you want to get data there are two options:

**1)** `@ViewChild` decorator

Define a `@Viewchild` in your component:

```
@ViewChild("myEditor", { static: false }) myEditor: any;
```

Then in your Html:

```
<ckeditor #myEditor [editor]="editor" [data]="data" [(ngModel)]="data"></ckeditor>
```

Now, you can get data with the following code :

```
this.myEditor.data
```

**2)** Change Event

Import the following line  in your component :

```
import { ChangeEvent } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/ckeditor.component";
```

Define a variable in your component named `retrieveddata` to store data

```
retrieveddata: string = null;
```

Put the following method in your component as `chagneEvent`

```
public onChange({ editor }: ChangeEvent) {
 const data = editor.getData();
 this.retrieveddata=data;
}
```

Then in your Html :

```
<ckeditor [editor]="editor" [data]="data" [(ngModel)]="data" (change)="onChange($event)"></ckeditor>
```

Now, your data is stored in `retrieveddata` variable. console it to see.

[**StackBlitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c4ursu).

[**DEMO**](https://angular-c4ursu.stackblitz.io/) (check your browser's console)

Comment: @Jay - I spent several hours time to know what is the problem, and finally, I found out the problem - I edited my example completely and tested locally. it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a reference to the instance of the editor, which would be `this.Editor.ckeditorInstance.getData()`

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#how-to-get-the-editor-instance-object-from-the-dom-element

Comment: in the console if I try to watch the value of this.Editor.ckeditorInstance I am getting undefined, Can it be difference for classic editor?